# custom class can't display 2d array c#(unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code

**CustomClass.cs**

```
public string[,] tableBR{ get; set; }

string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};
string data = "";
public int X_LENGTH = 104;
public int Y_LENGTH = 15;

public Scoreboard(string data)
{
    data = data;
    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        data += strData [i];
        data += ",";
    }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return "this are all the data :" + data;
}
```

**MainClass.cs**

```
string data = "";


void Start()
{
    Scoreboard scoreBoard = new Scoreboard(data);
    string s = string.Format ("{0}", scoreBoard);
    Debug.Log ("The data is : " + s);
}
```

Why can't I display my string data to the console in Unity . Could someone help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you just copied it in wrong, but `strData` is just an array with a single string in it...

Comment: What are you expecting this line: `data = data;` to do? You are working on the *local* copy of `data`, not the class copy. Please change the class field name to something else, like `_data` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RonBeyer it should be like this `this.data = _data` right sir?

Comment: No, rename the class field `data`, to `_data`, then you can do `_data = data;`, or you can use some other naming scheme, just make the class field name different from the constructor parameter name.

Comment: @maccettura This isn't the first [unity3d] question I've seen that is asking about "arrays" that just have a single comma-delimited string in them. I wonder if there isn't a blog post or something that is responsible for this "pattern"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `data` from the current instace of the class and not the `data` passed in as a parameter.Use the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) keyword. Your constructor should look like:

```
public Scoreboard(string data)
{
    this.data = data;
    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        this.data += strData [i];
        this.data += ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay then what next sir . It still couldn't display my `Debug.Log()` on my main class

Comment: @ChristianTindoc Did it print `"The data is : "` to the console?

Comment: Yes . Thank you very much . :)

Comment: Can i ask 1 more last question sir ?? If it's alright

Comment: I tried using it on the void method like this `public void MakeBR(string data){}` but it's giving me an error saying `overload method match for string.format`

Comment: I'm calling it on my main class like this `string s = string.Format ("{0}", ScoreBoard.MakeBR(data));`

Comment: @ChristianTindoc The problem is that your function is `void`, which means it won't return anything. You should make it `public string MakeBR(string data){...}` and return a string from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your local variable is hiding your instance variable. Try:

```
public Scoreboard(string data)
{
    this.data = data;
    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        this.data += strData [i];
        this.data += ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've the same names for input parameter and the member field of your class which prevents you from filling the correct one.

```
public Scoreboard(string data)
{
    data = data; // << HERE
    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        data += strData [i];
        data += ",";
    }
}
```

To fix your problem:

- change the name of `data` in your parameter to something else like `dataInput`:

  ```
  public string[,] tableBR{ get; set; }

  string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};
  string data = "";
  public int X_LENGTH = 104;
  public int Y_LENGTH = 15;

  public Scoreboard(string dataInput)
  {
      data = dataInput;
      for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
      {
          data += strData [i];
          data += ",";
      }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
      return "this are all the data :" + data;
  }
  ```
- rename member field called `data` to something else like `dataInput`:

  ```
  public string[,] tableBR{ get; set; }

  string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};
  string dataInput = "";
  public int X_LENGTH = 104;
  public int Y_LENGTH = 15;

  public Scoreboard(string data)
  {
      dataInput = data;
      for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
      {
          dataInput += strData [i];
          dataInput += ",";
      }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
      return "this are all the data :" + dataInput;
  }
  ```
- use `this.data` whenever you want to refer to the member field:

  ```
  public string[,] tableBR{ get; set; }

  string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};
  string data = "";
  public int X_LENGTH = 104;
  public int Y_LENGTH = 15;

  public Scoreboard(string data)
  {
      this.data = data;
      for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
      {
          this.data += strData [i];
          this.data += ",";
      }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
      return "this are all the data :" + this.data;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much . I'll upvote this sir but i don't have much reputation